# Pushnotifications not received when sent from azure instance

Tags: azure, google-cloud-messaging

I have got a strange problem with Push notifications, when sent in bulk from Azure instance using the GCM server key, the push messages are not getting received in the devices. But, it works fine when I do the same thing in my local machine. I didn't use any of the azure push services. Is there any configuration that I would have to enable to make it work. I have also got the `messageid` from GCM cloud for each and every push message. Any help would be appreciated.

Please let me know if you need more information

EDIT : Does Azure allows an adhoc webapplication to push notifications? I see there are certain kind of mobile services provided by Azure. Do we need to compulsorily use those services to push notifications?

Comment: Are you doing a HTTP push or an XMPP push? If HTTP, what's the HTTP [response code](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#error-codes) that gets returned? If you're doing XMPP, have you ensured the relevant port is open on the firewall?

Comment: I'm doing HTTP push using gcm [Server.java](https://code.google.com/r/dusent13-gcmdemo/source/browse/gcm-server/src/com/google/android/gcm/server/Sender.java?r=4b9fe231d04eb08f75f2cb4b16d3f785a41413f8) class file. I have also got the success response code 200. I have removed the application from azure and have deployed in our network itself. It works now. I'm not sure what happened with azure.

Comment: Here's a step by step tutorial for GCM on Azure: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-javascript-backend-android-get-started-push/#configure-mobile-services-to-send-push-requests. Basically you need a handler class to handle push notifications in Azure.